# Dart, how to transform from one iterable to another?

Tags: loops, iterator, dart

I have something like:

```
Element html = DivElement();
```

and I add some children from a list of types which have a html element property:

```
for(var base in bases){

    html.children.add(base.html);

}
```

Is there a way of doing this in Dart like you can in C# syntax?

```
html.children.addAll(base.select(o => o.html)); //no need for a for-in loop now
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use map:

```
html.children.addAll(bases.map((o) => o.html));
```

done.

Comment: Just to be complete: "base" should be "bases" in your solution.